# Notepad++ shows empty lines in search

Tags: notepad++, search

When I search for a specific term in multiple files with search mode "regluar expressions" Notepad++ shows me a lot of empty lines. There are about 120 empty lines, then a search result, then again about 120 empty lines. What am I doing wrong? My search term is "2016.08.01 06:".

[image: The empty lines when I search for a keyword]

Comment: That search term doesn’t look like a regular expression.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed I searched multiple words before, nevertheless when I change my search mode the empty lines still show up.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4452/p4mpzgzu_png.htm

Comment: Can you also [edit] the question and provide some sample data?

Comment: Actually I don't know if I may publish the data results because it's for my work. The result is just some log file text f.e. "2016.08.01 12:00 - ERROR - The camera stopped recording"

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar of the window suggests that there is more text to the right. Might there be lots of tabs or spaces at the left-hand-end of the lines found? The "Find" windows has "Normal" selected, not "Regular expressions", but the first sentence of question says otherwise.

Comment: Your question does not align with your screenshot. In your screenshot regular expressions are not selected, you are not in the "Find in files" window (or are you using "find in all open documents" ?) and "match whole word only" is not selected (it is by default). Please update the discription of what you are doing and how.